# Docker client freeze

Tags: linux, service, docker

the architecture is simple,
I have a small bash script that orchestrate 
two types of containers:
 
1 member of type "1" talks to another member of type "2". about 15 containers of each type.
When I detect that a member of type "2" (or "1") died, i kill the other one and raise them again.

the environment is Amazon ec2, 8 core, ubuntu 14.04.

After some period of time, when trying to do 'docker ps', i get no response.
I think that the problem is the amount of times i issue 'docker stop' command.
when i did 'docker kill' instead, the problem occurs faster.
Reading the documentation i see that 'docker stop' command coincide with what i see in the docker.log - which is a lot of docker kill (this is what happens when a container does not respond to a 'docker stop' command).
Is there a problem with the docker stop/kill - and the docker memory management?

Answer (score 0):

That could be linked to [issue 15101](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15101), where daemon containers have trouble to be killed.

> I still have this issue on docker 1.8.1.
>   Removing `/etc/apparmor.d/docker` and running `sudo service apparmor reload` appears to fix it

Comment: Thanks for the quick response VonC, but the guy added there:
"But then I can no longer start any containers..."

Answer (score 0):

This look like a problem in the docker infrastructure, there is a pretty big thread on the subject that looks like what i asked here, i will post an answer when this issue resolve there.

[Docker Daemon Hangs under load](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13885)